# Capturing Method name and line number in Application Insights for a Java Application

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to configure the Application Insights in my Java Application. My logs are going into the the Application Insights, but it doesn't capture all the infos from logs like method name, line number etc.

For example,
actual log from application,
01:33:21 main INFO org.hibernate.Version **logVersion:44** - HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.17.Final

Logs going into the Application Insights.
{"ver":1,"name":"Message","time":"2022-01-19T01:33:21.84Z","iKey":"79711330-d3a7-45f0-bec4-ee9489ae28bb","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"java:3.2.4","ai.cloud.role":"RunId:-703","ai.operation.id":"663549a66c4997600ced2a378044a48d","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"aaaa"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.17.Final","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"fileName":"BatchRunExecutor","LoggerName":"org.hibernate.Version","LoggingLevel":"INFO","SourceType":"Logger","ThreadName":"main","dirName":"nodir"}}}}

It is missing the method name, line number etc. So how can I tune AI to capture these additional info.

I am using applicationinsights-agent-3.2.4.jar to push the logs.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score -1):

You can check with Azure Monitor OpenTelemetry based to configure your own logs for Java Applications.

Can be achieved with below steps:

1. Set application insights connection as environmental variable as below:

   ```
    APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING=InstrumentationKey=...
   ```
2. Check connection string for AI resource.
3. Configure settings in applicationinsights,json settings.
4. Also can set user id with adding open telemetry api and setting user_id in your code.

For more detail information, refer to [MS Docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent)